# Scene Builder (JavaFX) Button Disable Condition

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm using Scene Builder 2.0 and I want to make a button be disabled by default. That is working fine, but I want to make it enabled if two booleans are set to true. In Scene Builder how do I add a condition to a button's state?

So the launchButton method below is what will happen when the button is clicked. And the booleans in the checkBox methods should be connected to Scene Builder somehow.

Thanks so much!

```
public void checkBox1(ActionEvent event) {
    checkBox1.setDisable(true);
    checkBox1Status = true;
}

public void checkBox2(ActionEvent event) {
    checkBox2.setDisable(true);
    checkBox2Status = true;
}

public void launchButton(ActionEvent event) throws InterruptedException {
    progressBarMainMenu(event);
}
```

Comment: Put a listener on your checkboxes that will update the button when clicked/changed. In code (not in scene builder). Don't know if possible directly in scene builder (think not)

Comment: updating button state like: but.setDisable(checkbox1.isSelected && checkbox2.isSelected);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with Scene Builder.
The tool is about generating an FXML file, that doesn't contain code logic.

Comment: Actually you might be able to define a conditional value for a property in FXML (and perhaps also scene builder), using an [expression binding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#expression_binding).  Not that I would necessarily recommend that approach if it could be done, but it is perhaps possible.